# Iterate through datagridviewcolumn using rows property

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a

```
Dictionary<string, DataGridViewColumn> junctionTableDependencies = new Dictionary<string, DataGridViewColumn>();
```

I want to iterate through the values of the dictionary which are columns for a certain value of a cell using the rows property but it seems i dont have it

```
foreach(DataGridViewColumn searchCol  in junctionTableDependencies.Values)
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in **searchCol**.)
                                            if(value==row.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
```

How can i iterate through the column vertically without the **row.Cells[0]** thing?

Answer (score 0):

You have the `DataGridViewColumn` so you need to find the `DataGridView` it belongs to and then enumerate the rows of the found grid:

```
foreach(DataGridViewColumn searchCol in junctionTableDependencies.Values)
{
   foreach(DataGridViewRow thisRow in searchCol.DataGridView.Rows)
   {
      var value = thisRow.Cells[searchCol.Name];
      if (value == "whateverYouNeed")
      {
         // Code...
      }
   }
}
```